# Why doesn't Kotlin Array<T> implement Iterable<T>

Tags: types, interface, kotlin

Why doesn't the [`Array<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) class in `Kotlin` implement [`Iterable<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html)?

A quick look at the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) reveals that it already has an [`iterator()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/iterator.html) method too.

Comment: a solution for not being able to implement generic functions for arrays is to use the `List` interface whenever possible

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Kotlin is designed to be fully interoperable with Java. `Array<X>` is `X[]` both at runtime and from Java's point of view. Java arrays don't implement `Iterable`, so Kotlin arrays (which are virtually the same) do not as well.

We *could* make our arrays implement `Iterable` by creating a standalone class which does not relate to Java arrays. However, in order to maintain compatibility with Java, we'd have to perform implicit conversions from such type to Java arrays and back. Implicit conversions are generally not the perfect approach because of performance overhead and unclear object identity semantics. Here they would also solve only a half of the problem, since you'd still have to manually "box" arrays when calling Kotlin code from Java. This is why such solution was not considered as feasible.

Comment: To add: [`asIterable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-iterable.html) will give you a wrapper object that is `Iterable`.

Comment: In addition to `asIterable`, there is also [`asList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-list.html).